# Can we show the block matrix of the inverse of $A$ is greater than the inverse of the block matrix of $A$?

Tags: matrices, inverse, positive-definite, block-matrices, matrix-analysis

I know we have the relation $\left( A_{ii} \right) ^{-1}\le \left( A^{-1} \right) _{ii}$ where $A$ is a positive definite matrix. My problem is, can we extend the result to block matrices with $C\preceq D$ stands for $D-C$ is positive semi-definite? That is, $\left( A_{\left[ ii \right]} \right) ^{-1}\preceq \left( A^{-1} \right) _{\left[ ii \right]}$ with $[ii]$ stands for the $ii$th block?

For example, if $$A=\left( \begin{matrix}
 A_{11}&  A_{12}\\
 A_{12}^{\dagger}&  A_{22}\\
\end{matrix} \right) $$ with $A_{11},A_{12},A_{22}$ matrices instead of numbers, can I show that $$\left( A^{-1} \right)_{11}\succeq \left( A_{11} \right)^{-1}$$ where $\left( A^{-1} \right) _{11}$ is the upper left submatrix of $A^{-1}$?

Comment: Maybe this [lanswer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/324892) helps? If you extract a diagonal block from a pos def matrix, it is also pos def...

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I added more details in the problem.

Comment: I would use $\succeq$ (`\succeq`) and $\preceq$ (`\preceq`) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is symmetric and positive-definite, then the answer is yes.

It follows, e.g., straight from the matrix inversion Lemma (e.g., Matrix Analysis by Horn or this mathoverflow [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423087/a-property-of-directed-acyclic-graph/423103#423103)) or standard blockwise inverse results (as the one in Appendix).

**Lemma.** Let $A\in\mathbb{S}_{++}^N$ be an $N\times N$ positive-definite symmetric matrix. Let $S\subset \left\{1,2,\ldots,N\right\}$. Then,

$$\left[A^{-1}\right]_{S}\succeq \left(A_S\right)^{-1},$$

where $B_{S}$ or $\left[B\right]_S$ is the $\left|S\right|\times \left|S\right|$ submatrix formed with the elements of $B$ indexed by $S\times S$.

*Proof.*

From the inversion Lemma (or refer to the Appendix below), you have

$$\left(A_S\right)^{-1}=\left[A^{-1}\right]_S-\underbrace{\left[A^{-1}\right]_{SS'}\left(\left[A^{-1}\right]_{S'}\right)^{-1}\left[A^{-1}\right]_{S'S}}_{=:\mathcal{E}_S},$$

where $S'$ is the complement of $S$ and $\mathcal{E}_S$ may be interpreted as the error matrix that stems from commuting the projection $\left[\cdot\right]_{S}$ and the inversion $\left(\cdot\right)^{-1}$ operations.

Therefore, $\left[A^{-1}\right]_S \succeq \left(A_S\right)^{-1}$ if and only if $\mathcal{E}_S\succeq 0$.

It is straighforward to check that $\mathcal{E}_S\succeq 0$. Indeed, if $A\succ 0$, then $\left(\left[A^{-1}\right]_{S'}\right)^{-1}\succ 0$, as the positive-definiteness property is preserved under projection $\left[\cdot\right]_S$ and inversion $\left(\cdot\right)^{-1}$. Further, since $A$ is symmetric, then $\left[A^{-1}\right]_{SS'}$ is the transpose of $\left[A^{-1}\right]_{S'S}$.

----------------- Appendix: Blockwise inversion -------------------------

Since $A$ is invertible and symmetric, we can write it as
$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\widetilde{A} & \widetilde{B}\\ \widetilde{B}^{\top} & \widetilde{D}
\end{array}\right]^{-1}.$

From [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion) inverse block matrix result in equation (2), -- that relates the sub-block $A_S$ with the Schur Complement of $A^{-1}$ -- we have

$$A_S=\left(\left[A^{-1}\right]_S-\left[A^{-1}\right]_{SS'}\left(\left[A^{-1}\right]_{S'}\right)^{-1}\left[A^{-1}\right]_{S'S}\right)^{-1},$$

since $\left[A^{-1}\right]_S=\widetilde{A}$; $\left[A^{-1}\right]_{S'}=\widetilde{D}$; $\left[A^{-1}\right]_{SS'}=\widetilde{B}$ and $\left[A^{-1}\right]_{SS'}=\widetilde{B}^{\top}$. Therefore,

$$\left(A_S\right)^{-1}=\left[A^{-1}\right]_S-\left[A^{-1}\right]_{SS'}\left(\left[A^{-1}\right]_{S'}\right)^{-1}\left[A^{-1}\right]_{S'S}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you generously point out where the matrix inversion lemma is in Horn's book? Thanks again!

Comment: I do not have the book with me. But it follows from one of these block inversion results (involving the Schur complement). I updated my answer with a particular result.